# Can we use DynamoDB transaction library with tablename override, if we are using mapper object?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB mapper for performing CRUD operations on DynamoDB. I have tablename overrides in place to use different table names for different regions. I want to use DynamoDB transaction library, however I am not able to find a way to provide override for table name with mapper.

TO add to this, I want to perform override for two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked various transaction documentation avavilable and it was clear to me that transaction library only allows single tableName override. If you are using **TableNameOverride** for all your tables using transaction is difficult (If you are dealing with multiple tables in a single transaction). I realized, may be I am using **TableNameOverride** incorrectly in the system.

After some research I found the following [link](https://medium.com/@onclouds/aws-lambda-use-different-dynamodb-tables-for-different-stages-5eda9f5378b2)
The solution talks about how you can manage different table name in different environments using **TableNameResolver**.
What I was looking for was independence to use unique table names in different enviroments if I had to. It should be easier for me to choose whatever name I want.

That's when I came up with this:

MyTableNameResolver class

```
public class MyTableNameResolver extends DynamoDBMapperConfig.DefaultTableNameResolver {

    private Map<Class<?>, String> classToTableNameMap;

    public MyTableNameResolver(final Map<Class<?>, String> classToTableNameMap) {
        super();
        this.classToTableNameMap = classToTableNameMap;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName(final Class<?> clazz, final DynamoDBMapperConfig config) {
     if (!classToTableNameMap.containsKey(clazz)) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Appropriate Message");
     }
     return classToTableNameMap.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

The way you initialize DynamoDB mapper is:

```
TableNameResolver tableNameReolver = new MyTableNameResolver(dynamoDBTableMap);
// dynamoDBTableMap - this map can be constructed using some mapping from config file
DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().withTableNameResolver(tableNameReolver).build();
```

Now you don't need to perform any tablename overrides anywhere, that means one less thing to worry about and transactions can be used easily.